# show data of each circle of bubble chart in table d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I made a bubble chart and is working fine.But i need and even based feature in which i click on each circle and the data related to that circle will show in tabular form in another div..

```
<div id="bubblechart"></div>
<div id="table"></div>
```

first div contain the bubble chart and working fine. table div is used as container for the table generated.

here is my code.

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                  .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
                  .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
                  .enter().append("g")
                  .attr("class", "node")
                  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
node.append("circle")
                  .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
                  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); })
                  .on("mouseover", animateFirstStep)
                  .on("mouseout", animateSecondStep);
node.append("text")
                  .attr("dy", ".3em")
                  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                  .text(function(d) { return d.className; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an .on("click", clickFunction) to the node.  This will work like your mouseover and mouseout lines.

In the clickFunction function, control the content of the target div using

```
document.getElementById('targetDiv').innerHTML = targetText;
```

or with jQuery

```
$("#targetDiv").html(targetText);
```

Comment: how can i get the data related to that circle that is the question

Comment: actually the target text is the json data linked with the circle.. the number of circle represents the various element in the data.

Comment: It depends on the structure of your data. You need to link the content you want in the table to data using a key, or index value. For example: "$("#table").html(d.className);" will put the class name in the table div

Comment: on mouseover i am calling this function
function animateSecondStep(){
        d3.select(this)
          .transition()
            .duration(100)
            .style("stroke","")
            .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; });
      };
so that i am able to get the d.className using this object.. how can i do according to your method

Comment: I think what confuses Saurabh Sinha (and me as well) is how the showInfo function in your example takes the argument `d` and automatically links `d` to the JSON data, since it is not preceeded by the data method.

Comment: When you call a function on an element in d3, the data bound to that element is passed into the function automatically. In the showInfo example the element is node. Node is linked to graph.nodes as data.  So, each element in the graph.nodes array is passed to the function. You see this behavior in many of the examples. See the click function here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4699541